# Attribute compatibility not disabled by semantic actions

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I have a grammar rule that looks like this:

```
rule<Iterator, utree()> expr, factor;

expr =
    (
       +(
           (
              toks.symbol // toks.symbol attribute type is an std::string
              [
                 // I'm trying to force the attribute type to be utree
                 _val = construct<utree::list_type>()
                 // some code here
              ]
           |  (
                 factor >>
                +(
                    // the 3 tokens here have unsigned long attribute
                    toks.arrow >> factor
                 |  toks.squiggleArrow >> factor
                 |  toks.dot >> factor
                 )
              )
              [

                 // I'm trying to force the attribute type to be utree
                 _val = construct<utree::list_type>()
                 // some code here
              ]
           ) >> toks.assign // toks.assign is token_def<omit>
        ) >> factor
     ) [ _val = ternary(_1, _2) ]
   ;
```

As far as I understand from here:

http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/attribute-propagation-and-attribute-compatibility/

attribute compatibility should be disabled in this case because semantic 
actions are there. Nonetheless, I'm seeing a compilation error inside 
ternary() that suggests that the type of _1 is not a vector as I 
would expect, but rather it is:

```
vector<
    variant<std::string,
            fusion::vector2<utree,
                            fusion::vector2<long unsigned int, utree>
                           >
           >
       >
```

which means that for some reason, semantic actions didn't kick in!

Any hints why this is happening?

**Note:** I pasted a minimized example showing the problem here:

http://pastebin.com/rgiy2QBW

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment that the compiler complains about is inside the `ternaryImpl::operator()` body, which means that, obviously, the semantic actions did kick in!

Now, although you are right that SA's prevent automatic attribute propagation (unless operator %= is used for rule assignment), this does **not** mean that the type exposed by the primitive parsers magically changes.

The type you list in the question, accurately reflects what the parser expressions / operators will return:

- Or (`|`) parses into a variant
- Sequence (`>>`) parses into a `fusion::vector2<...>` etc.

Now, here is my simple, minimal change that will make this compile. The trick is, precisely, to make attribute assignment work *for* you, by splitting a subrule out *with an explicit attribute type*. This allows Spirit to do the attribute conversion for you.

```
struct Parser: public qi::grammar<Iterator, utree()>
{
    template <typename Tokens>
        Parser(const Tokens &toks):
            Parser::base_type(expression)
    {
        chain = +(
            (
               toks.symbol
               [
                  _val = construct<utree::list_type>()
                  // some code here
               ]
            |  (
                  factor >>
                 +(
                     toks.arrow >> factor
                  |  toks.dot >> factor
                  )
               )
               [
                  _val = construct<utree::list_type>()
                  // some code here
               ]
            ) >> toks.assign
         );
        expression = factor
            | (chain >> factor) [ _val = ternary(_1, _2) ]
            ;
    }

   rule<Iterator, utree::list_type()> chain;
   rule<Iterator, utree()> expression, factor, test;
};
```

> **Note**: *if you want you should be able to do the same without extra rule definitions (using `qi::attr_cast<>`, `qi::as<>` e.g.) but I doubt it will be readable/maintainable.*

**PS.** Similar points can be taken away from the [`calc_utree_naive.cpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc_utree_naive.cpp) which, necessarily, spells more explicit rule attribute types than the [`calc_utree_ast.cpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc_utree_ast.cpp) version, which uses SA's.

Here is the complete, compiling version, with some inline notes in comments:

```
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
// #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_utree.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>

namespace lex    = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi     = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace phx    = boost::phoenix;

using lex::token_def;
using qi::rule;
using qi::_1;
using qi::_2;
using qi::_val;
using spirit::utree;
using phx::construct;

// base iterator type
typedef std::string::iterator BaseIteratorT;

// token type
typedef lex::lexertl::token<BaseIteratorT, boost::mpl::vector</*double, int, */std::string> > TokenT;

// lexer type
typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<TokenT> LexerT;

template <typename LexerT>
struct Tokens: public lex::lexer<LexerT>
{
   Tokens()
   {
      using lex::_pass;
      using lex::pass_flags;

      // literals
      symbol = "[a-zA-Z_?](\\w|\\?)*|@(\\w|\\?)+";
      arrow  = "->";
      dot    = '.';
      assign = "=";

      // literal rules
      this->self += symbol;
      this->self += arrow;
      this->self += dot;
      this->self += assign;
   }

   ~Tokens() {}

   // literal tokens
   token_def<std::string> symbol;
   token_def<> arrow, dot; // HINT: lex::omit here? 
   /*
    * ^ Otherwise, expect these to be all exposed as Qi attributes as well, so
    * _1, _2, _3, _4 a bit more than you'd expect
    */
   token_def<lex::omit> assign;
};

struct ternaryImpl
{
   template <typename Expr1Type, typename Expr2Type>
   struct result { typedef utree type; };

   template <typename Expr1Type, typename Expr2Type>
   utree operator()(Expr1Type &vec, Expr2Type &operand) const {
      utree ret;

      for (typename Expr1Type::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
         // some code
         ret = *it;
         // more code
      }

      // some code here

      return ret;
   }
};

phx::function<ternaryImpl> ternary = ternaryImpl();

template <typename Iterator>
struct Parser: public qi::grammar<Iterator, utree()>
{
    template <typename Tokens>
        Parser(const Tokens &toks):
            Parser::base_type(expression)
    {
        chain = +(
            (
               toks.symbol
               [
                  _val = construct<utree::list_type>()
                  // some code here
               ]
            |  (
                  factor >>
                 +(
                     toks.arrow >> factor
                  |  toks.dot >> factor
                  )
               )
               [
                  _val = construct<utree::list_type>()
                  // some code here
               ]
            ) >> toks.assign
         );
        expression = factor
            | (chain >> factor) [ _val = ternary(_1, _2) ]
            ;
    }

   rule<Iterator, utree::list_type()> chain;
   rule<Iterator, utree()> expression, factor, test;
};

int main()
{
   typedef Tokens<LexerT>::iterator_type IteratorT;

   Tokens<LexerT> l;
   Parser<IteratorT> p(l);
}
```